# Grouping multiple rows to one single row

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I have a set of data that has multiple attributes for one single row.

For example, each employee can participate in multiple activities and each activities has a score. When I query from the database, the `EmployeeID` will be repeated in all the rows like this:

[image]

What I want is to do a `group by` of sort on the data such that the each row is one Employee record with its activity and score like so:

[image]

I attempted to do a group by like this:

```
select Employee.EmployeeID, Games.Activity, Games.Score from Employee left join Games on Employee.GameID = Games.GameID
group by Employee.EmployeeID;
```

This however doesn't work. What should I do to do a group by without using a aggregation function in the select clause?

Comment: Do you mean that the employee id fields should be empty on those rows? I don't really see any grouping in here.

Comment: This is a formatting issue, not a data issue from the looks of it. You should consider doing this in the application code.

Comment: @JamesZ I meant it will be grouped. So the dark horizontal lines represent one row. Ignore the faint lines produced by the spreadsheet.

Answer (score 0):

1.User Window function `Row_number()` with Partition by `EmployeeID`

2.Then simply use `Case when then` to Get 1st Rows as EmployeeID

```
select case when NewTab.RN =1 then NewTab.EmployeeID else null,NewTab.Activity, NewTab.Score
from (
select ROW_NUMBER() OVER(partition BY Employee.EmployeeID ORDER BY Employee.EmployeeID)RN,* from (
select Employee.EmployeeID, Games.Activity, Games.Score from Employee 
left join Games on Employee.GameID = Games.GameID
group by Employee.EmployeeID)D
)NewTab
```

Comment: I don't quite understand the first step "User Window function Row_number() with Partition by EmployeeID". What is that user window function for?

Comment: @Carven https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/learn-sql-server/window-functions-in-sql-server/